# How does a SortedSet enforce its ordering constraint?

Tags: java, collections

A Java class implementing SortedSet is supposed to provide an iterator that iterates its elements in ascending order, in addition to some other methods. But I see no way that the SortedSet interface specification enforces this behavioral constraint that it specifies. SortedSet just has a few methods that an implementing class can implement without actually having to comply with the requirement of returning an ascending iterator, or indeed of having a valid comparator.

Just looking at the interface methods without knowing its name would not tell the developer the core behavior implementing classes are supposed to implement.

Is the implementing developer supposed to read the Javadoc and follow the specification to implement correctly ? Isn't SortedSet supposed to ensure that implementing classes actually return an ascending iterator .. What is the point of that interface otherwise?

Comment: "Is the implementing developer supposed to read the Javadoc and follow the specification to implement correctly?" yes.

Comment: "Isn't SortedSet supposed to ensure" no, it's a contract and you're welcome to break it if you want to cause problems for yourself. If you for some reason decide to implement a `SortedSet`, then you better do it correctly and read all the related documentation. If you don't, it's your own fault.

Comment: In general the answer is: a programmer better knows and understands what they are doing. Meaning: when you write code that is supposed to follow an interface coming out of some library, then you are **absolutely** supposed to read the relevant documentation/information and follow that precisely.

Comment: @Sweeper , for a language whose core philosophy, or at least USP is developer hand holding, IMO they should have added a way for an interface to enforce the behavioral contract specified in its documentation. Just relying on a developer to see the word Sorted and add ordering to an implementing class is sheer laziness or lack of thought IMO.

Comment: @programmerravi -  If the programmer doesn't bother to follow the documentation that lays out the requirements for the interface he's implementing, it's the **language designer** that's lazy?

Comment: @programmerravi Implementing interfaces such as SortedSet (or any other interface that define a contract) is not an everyday task, and certainly not many programmers do it. In the relatively rare case when someone is writing an implementation (say, a collections library that focuses on performance), they obviously have to pay attention to the contract and the JDK documentation. Otherwise, as I mentioned in the answer, their implementation is simply "buggy" and people will be reporting issues to them. Also enforcing such a contract is really a testing aspect, think unit tests, etc.

Comment: Forget about sorted, the `Iterator` itself has a contract that is not enforced but has to be known by the implementer. Same for `equals`, `hashCode`, and `toString` for every class that overrides them.

Answer (score 1):

An interface typically acts as a contract or a blueprint, that an implementation will conform to. The purpose of `SortedSet` is really to provide a standard interface for sorted sets that code can use, while allowing to switch the implementation (for example to a more performant one).

So the answer is yes the implementation must conform to the Javadocs which formally document the contract. Any implementation that does not do follow the documented behavior is simply considered a buggy one.